# Accessing a resource that is in separate JAR file from main code

Tags: java, file, jar, war

I am writing a project that is packaged as a WAR file and is structured as follows:

```
MyProject.war

| --- META-INF/
| --- WEB-INF/
      |--- classes/ (My compiles project classes)
      |   |--- com
      |       |--- package
      |           |--- MyClass.class
      |--- lib/
          |--- random.jar
          |   |--- file1.txt
          |   |--- file2.txt
          |--- MyProject.jar
              |--- com
                  |--- package
                      |--- MyClass.class
```

How can I access `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` from my `MyClass.java` file as an input stream?

Comment: com.package.MyClass -> `<identifier> expected`  (that package structure leads to uncompilable code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the JAR containing the resources is in your classpath, you should be able to load them via the context classloader.

```
final InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
      .getResourceAsStream("file1.txt");
```